# How to create a plugin for google maps' "share via" list

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have tried to search for example for creating a plugin for the google maps such that it appears in the **share via** list that appears when one clicks share after selecting a location in google maps for android. since I don't know the exact terminology used for the plugin, probably thats why could't search for it on google search. Any kind of help is appreciated !

I have uploaded an image on flickr to explain the question clearly.(not enough credits yet)

http://www.flickr.com/photos/120188532@N04/13108649615/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for Intent filters. This is described in the following guide from Android.

See:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

Comment: i don't think that the intents as in suggested by you  would suffice. Please see the image i've uploaded for clarity on the question. Thanks

Comment: It will be. Basically implementing you saying that you're application can receive intent. This way when the basic sent to for example is being used. Your'e app will be displayed in the list.